# Describe the set of vectors that are orthogonal to $[5\; 3]$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

> Let $v = [5\; 3]$. Describe the set of vectors $[x\; y]$ that are orthogonal to $v$.

I know it's a line, but what would the span be?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In your case, i suggest you read the notes of your teacher. The question you asked is somehow too easy to ask! (Also, you didn't mention your problem... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see orthogonal in a question, think dot product 0.

So, you want vectors $(x,y)$ with 
$$
(x,y)\cdot (5,3)=0\implies 5x+3y=0
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: okay so you -5/3x = y.

Comment: @amr bingo {}{}{}

Comment: So does that mean it span={[-3 5]} ??

Comment: @AmR yes. {}{}{}

Answer (score 2):

The vector $v$ represents a line through the origin with slope $3/5$, so the line through the origin with slope $-5/3$ would be orthogonal. This can be represented by any vector $[-3z \ 5z]$ for any $z\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: could you explain how you got to [-3x 5z] ?

Comment: The vector $[x \ y]$ has a "rise" of $y$ and a "run" of $x$, so the slope is $y/x$. So what vectors have a slope of $-5/3$? Well $[-3 \ 5]$ would be one ($5/(-3) = -5/3$), but so would $[-6 \ 10]$. In fact, any multiple of $[-3 \ 5]$ will have the same ratio of $-5/3$, so we can say $[-3z \ 5z]$ for any real $z$. To check, the ratio is $5z/(-3z) = -5/3$, the ratio we need.